# Reading Raw Bytes using Scapy?

Tags: python, networking, dns, scapy

I have a project in which I am building a DNS Forwarder.

I am using a UDP Server socket to listen to the DNS requests on port 53 (client is using the dig command) and I have to forward the received raw DNS request to scapy for dissecting it. I know that scapy is used to forge/send/manipulate packets.

The raw request looks something like this -

```
b'\xd6t\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03www\x08facebook\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00)\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Is there a method/function in scapy that is used to import the raw DNS requests to get the flags, what record is being asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialise a DNS payload with your byte string:

```py
from scapy.all import DNS
p = DNS(b'\xd6t\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03www\x08facebook\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00)\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

You can then access its field:

```py
print(p.id)
print(p.opcode)
...
```

**[Edit]**
And to print all its content:

```py
p.show()
```

Comment: Okay .. so this answer is partially correct. To get the fields, at the end of the p = DNS(........) we have to add ".show()"

Comment: @Mr.X Right. I edited my answer to add this possibility.